# fade out splash screen in react-native

Tags: react-native

Below is my code, I try to fade out an image and after fade out go to the login page.

It goes to login page but the animation is not working.

The image comes and wait then disappears immediately. What I am doing wrong ?

```
state={
        fadeAmin: new Animated.Value(0),
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        () => {
          Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
            this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
            {
              toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
              duration: 2000,
            }
          ).start();
        })            
    }

    componentWillMount() {
     setInterval(() => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('login');

     },2000) // Starts the animation
  }

    render() {
      let { fadeAnim } = this.state;     
      console.log('props', this.props)
        return (
          <View style = {{flex:1 , alignItems:"center", justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Login navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
            <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
            {this.props.children}

              <Image style= {styles.logo} source={require('../../image/dataLogo.jpeg')} />           

            </Animated.View>
          </View>

        );      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, after the fadeout you want to navigate to the login screen, in that case I am guessing the issue is with lifecycle methods.
So `componentWillMount` calls before `componentDidMount`, now even though you gave setTimeout (you really dont need that) its about exact time as your fade animation.
So to fix this I would suggest remove the `componentWillMount` and do all the logic in `componentDidMount`. The `start` takes a call back, it will be called after the animation is finished, you can take this opportunity to navigate wherever you want.
Also if you want additional time, add `setTimeout` then navigate.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
      this.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,
      }
    ).start(() => {
      console.log('fading out');
      // this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
      /* setTimeout(() => {
        this.fadeOut();
      }, 2000); */
    });

  }
```

Example, https://snack.expo.io/SkFnm_x8E

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: İf I want to fade in, what should I do in this code ? @Subhendu Kundu

Comment: So you wanna change `this.fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(1);` to `this.fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(0);`
and then `{
        toValue: 1,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,
      }`
you are all set. :)